# random function for generating quaternions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random

I need to generate random quaternions in Matlab in the range:

```
rand(varargin{i+1}, varargin{i}+1)
```

The output needs to be a quaternion of the format `[a b c d ]` (for example: `[1 2 3 4 ]`)

I don't know if this is possible in Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Use Matlab's rand function in the following way:

```
minVal + rand(1,4)*(maxVal-minVal)
```

In your case:

```
minVal = varargin{i+1};
maxVal = varargin{i}+1;
```

Comment: thank u but it for real number but me i need a quaterions number

Comment: @AmalTarghi it is a quaternion. The final result has the format [a b c d].

Comment: nooo i tried with this but the result is nooot [ a b c d ]                                                      a= plus( [-1 -1 -1 -1 ] , times(rand(varargin{i+1},varargin{i}+1),[2,2,2,2]))

Comment: @AmalTarghi what is the result which you receive?

Comment: Matrix dimensions must agree.